# Advanced friendship model and queries in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-network-friendship

I have friendship model, and for every new friendship, I create two new records:

- User1 and Friend1
- Friend1 and User1

I can retrieve all standard staffs like: friends, friendships, pending_friends... The situation becomes complicated when I try to get common friends, friends of friends...

For now to get common friendships, I use something like:

```
has_many :common_friendships, :class_name => 'Friendship', :conditions=>'friendships.user_id = #{self.id}' do
  def common_with(friend)
    joins("inner join friendships fl2 on friendships.friend_id = fl2.user_id").where("fl2.friend_id = #{friend.id}")
  end
end
```

Also I can use full query with `finder_sql` like:

```
select distinct *
from friendships fl1
inner join friendships fl2 on fl1.friend_id = fl2.user_id
where fl1.user_id = 1  and fl2.friend_id = 2
```

How can I do that in an elegant way in Rails 3?

Comment: Are you using single model for storing freinds and users information???

Comment: no of course. There is a User and Friendship model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement a Friendship Model in Rails 3 for a Social Networking Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612736/how-to-implement-a-friendship-model-in-rails-3-for-a-social-networking-applicati)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer on this question:

[How to Implement a Friendship Model in Rails 3 for a Social Networking Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612736/how-to-implement-a-friendship-model-in-rails-3-for-a-social-networking-applicatio)