# How to Implement a Friendship Model in Rails 3 for a Social Networking Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm currently working on a small social networking application and right now I'm trying to create a model that represents *friendships* between *users*. This is what I came up with so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

My *friendship* model has a field *confirmed* as boolean which I'd like to use
to define a friendship as pending or confirmed.

How can I access all pending request for a certain user? Can I somehow define
this using Rails' *scope* method? Something like

```
current_user.friendships.requests # => [Friendship, Friendship, ...]
```

would be great.

How can I make this association bidirectional? Do I simply add another
friendship once one has confirmed a friend request such that my friendship
table would look similar to this:

```
| user_id | friend_id | confirmed |
-----------------------------------
| 1       | 2         | true      |
| 2       | 1         | true      |
```

Comment: How does a friend differ from another user, other than the fact that they are linked through a friendship?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To access all pending friendships you can use an association:

```
has_many :pending_friends,
         :through => :friendships,
         :source => :friend,
         :conditions => "confirmed = 0"  # assuming 0 means 'pending'
```

To make the friendship bidirectional, you may want to replace your boolean *confirmed* column with a string *status* column that has one of the following three values: 'pending', 'requested' and 'accepted' (optionally 'rejected'). This will help keep track of who made the friendship request.

When a friendship request is sent (say from Foo to Bar), you create two friendship records (encapsulated in a transaction): one requested and one pending to reflect resp. that Bar has a requested friendship from Foo and Foo has a pending friendship with Bar.

```
  def self.request(user, friend)
    unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user, friend)
      transaction do
        create(:user => user, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
        create(:user => friend, :friend => user, :status => 'requested')
      end
    end
  end
```

When the friendship is accepted (e.g. by Bar), both friendship records are set to accepted.

```
  def self.accept(user, friend)
    transaction do
      accepted_at = Time.now
      accept_one_side(user, friend, accepted_at)
      accept_one_side(friend, user, accepted_at)
    end
  end

  def self.accept_one_side(user, friend, accepted_at)
    request = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
    request.status = 'accepted'
    request.accepted_at = accepted_at
    request.save!
  end
```

This is largely covered in chapter 14 of the Railspace book by Michael Hartl and Aurelius Prochazka. Here's the [source code](http://railsspace.com/book/chapter14) which should help you refine your solution.

Comment: Just to say thanks, you have helped me with the same problem, but in PHP. =) +1

Comment: Do you know which attributes should be accessible in the Friendship Model? I am assuming only the status attribute should be accessible. Am I correct?

Comment: hi @mbreining I came across your solution today, i don't know if there is actually a more powerful solution than this, but i think it's not a good idea to create two lines for a relationship between 2 users in the Friendships table, i post a new question here if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339596/the-best-way-to-implement-a-friendship-model-in-rails thank you

Answer (score 12):

The ultimate reference:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Answer (score 3):

A short answer is yes. Just make another friendship record to represent bidirectional association.

I wrote a gem called [has_friendship](https://github.com/sungwoncho/has_friendship) for this kind of problem. All you need to do is drop in `has_friendship` in your model, and all the associations and methods will be taken care of.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [this tutorial illustrating a relationship model](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec%3athe_relationship_model) on Rails Tutorials. It should be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the book RailsSpace: Building a Social Networking Website. It clearly explains how to implement a friendship model. Though it isnt extensible to other forms of relationship but is pretty applicable for your problem.

Comment: Do you know which attributes should be accessible in the Friendship Model? I am assuming only the status attribute should be accessible. Am I correct?