# Ruby on rails 3 friendship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to build a friendship system sorta following this link: [How to Implement a Friendship Model in Rails 3 for a Social Networking Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612736/how-to-implement-a-friendship-model-in-rails-3-for-a-social-networking-applicati). However the code seem to be very outdated, and I might of change it, what i am trying to do atm is simply to create a relationship, but this seem to not works.

So here my create

```
  #Send a friendship request
  def create
    Friendship.request(@customer, @friend)
    redirect_to friendships_path
  end
```

Which then technically would called the method request located in model which his already implemented in the previous post.

```
  def self.request(customer, friend)
    unless customer == friend or Friendship.exists?(customer, friend)
      transaction do
        create(:customer => customer, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
        create(:customer => friend, :friend => customer, :status => 'requested')
      end
    end
  end
```

and i also added these to the model

```
attr_accessible :status, :customer_id, :friend_id, :customer, :friend
```

However the friendship doesn't get created. Any reason why not? I call the relationship has follow

```
<%= link_to "Add friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => customer), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: Im trying to implement a friendship model myself and I am confused as to what I should be adding in attr_accessible. I would think status should be the only attribute in there. Isn't there a risk of malicious Users changing id's and thereby changing friendships between users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the @customer and @friend. In your link, you are setting :friend_id to the customer, and you are never setting the @customer id.

Try this:

```
def create
  @customer = current_account
  @friend = Account.find(params[:friend_id])
  Friendship.request(@customer, @friend)
  redirect
end
```

In the link_to you need:

```
<%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => friend),: method => :post %>
```