# BelongsToMany with one or vice versa relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and Eloquent.
I have a `courses` table and a Pivot table that holds the related courses.

My pivot table named `relatedCourses` has 2 columns, course1 & course2.
[image]

In the above example, Course ID 5 is related with Course ID 7.

```
$data["course"] = course::where("isActive",1)->with('related')->find(5);
```

This works and brings ID 7 as related.

If i try 
`$data["course"] = course::where("isActive",1)->with('related')->find(7)` it should bring ID 5 as related, this is what i'm trying to achieve.

My code is like this in the model :

```
class course extends Model
    {
        public function category()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\courseCategory',"categoryId");
        }

        public function related()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\course', 'relatedCourses', 'course1', 'course2');
        }
    }
```

Comment: pivot table is used to join two tables but i think you have only one table of courses so how can you define pivot relation with pivot table?

Comment: I have 2 tables, table1 holds all the courses, table2 holds the relations between them.

Comment: but which relation?

Comment: relation is Course With Course, one course is similar to another

Comment: like You have one Course and that course has many sub-courses?

Comment: Imagine we have course regarding cooking. Course 'Cook Potato in grill' has other similar courses like 'Cook Potato in oven'. I'm using a pivot table to set this relation. I'll post a database schema to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two relationships for this query.

```
class course extends Model
    {
        public function category()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\courseCategory',"categoryId");
        }

        public function relatedCourses()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course', 'relatedCourses', 'course1', 'course2');
        }

        public function originalCourses()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course', 'relatedCourses', 'course2', 'course1');
        }
    }
```

Then you can query your relations,

```
$data["course"] = course::where("isActive",1)->with('relatedCourses')->find(5);
```

and

```
$data["course"] = course::where("isActive",1)->with('originalCourses')->find(7);
```

To merge both relations you can do like this

```
$course = course::where("isActive",1)->with('originalCourses', 'relatedCourses')->get();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This will result in 2 different relations, i'm trying to set in 1 relation so i can do a foreach loop for $relatedCourses and not for both $relatedCourses and $originalCourses

Comment: that will not work dear you have to do foreach loop for both check this question and answer [self many to many relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567305/laravel-many-to-many-self-referencing-table-only-works-one-way?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: can at least we MERGE relatedCourses & originalCourses?

Comment: I decide to use your technique and then manually merge the 2 results in 1. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Yeah. This is the best way to do :)

Comment: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049753/friendship-system-with-laravel-many-to-many-relationship) this will help you in eager loading. And I have updated my answer. Not sure but this query(with both relations eagar loading) should work.