# Laravel Eloquent Inner Join on Self Referencing Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to **inner join a users table to itself using an eloquent model**. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find a solution to this **without creating two queries** which is what I am currently doing.

A **users** table has a **many to many** relationship itself through the **pivot** table **friends**

I tried and failed inner joining `Users::class` to itself. The best I can get at an inner join is by running two queries and seeing if there is an overlap. Thus one person has reached out to the other and vice versa.

```
friends   | users
----------|------
send_id   | id
receive_id| name
is_blocked|
```

### sample data & expected result

```
users.id | name
---------|------
1        | foo
2        | bar
3        | baz

friends
send_id | receive_id | is_blocked
--------|------------|-----------
1       |    2       |  0
2       |    1       |  0
1       |    3       |  0
3       |    1       |  1
2       |    3       |  0
```

The user should have an eloquent relationship called friends. It should be what you expect comes out of `requestedFriends` or `receivedFriends` just joined.

```
foo->friends
returns `baz`
bar->friends
returns `foo`
baz->friends
returns empty collection
```

### currently using

```php
// User.php
public function requestedFriends()
{
    $left = $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends','send_id','receive_id')
        ->withPivot('is_blocked')
        ->wherePivot('is_blocked','=', 0)
        ->withTimestamps();
    return $left;
}

public function receivedFriends()
{
    $right = $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends','receive_id','send_id')
        ->withPivot('is_blocked')
        ->wherePivot('is_blocked','=', 0)
        ->withTimestamps();

    return $right;
}

public function friends()
{
    $reqFriends = $this->requestedFriends()->get();
    $recFriends = $this->receivedFriends()->get();
    $req = explode(",",$recFriends->implode('id', ', '));
    $intersect = $reqFriends->whereIn('id', $req);
    return $intersect;
}
```

### Research so far

[Laravel Many to many self referencing table only works one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567305/laravel-many-to-many-self-referencing-table-only-works-one-way) -> old question, but still relevant

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/441#issuecomment-14213883 -> yep, it works… but one way.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein
currently the only way I have found to do this in eloquent.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins -> **Ideally** I would find a solution using an innerjoin onto itself, but no matter which way I put the id's I couldn't get a solution to work.

### A solution would

A solution would inner join a self referencing table using eloquent in **laravel 5.7** or **5.8**, where a relationship only exists if `send_id` & `receive_id` are present on multiple rows in the friends table.

**OR**

Somehow let the community know that this can't be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I have not checked this solution in every detail yet, but I have written a "ManyToMany" Class extending the "BelongsToMany" Class shipped with laravel, which appears to work.
The class basically just overrides the "get" method, duplicating the original query, "inverting" it and just performing a "union" on the original query.

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Eloquent\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class ManyToMany extends BelongsToMany
{

    /**
     * Execute the query as a "select" statement.
     *
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function get($columns = ['*'])
    {
        // duplicated from "BelongsToMany"
        $builder = $this->query->applyScopes();

        $columns = $builder->getQuery()->columns ? [] : $columns;

        // Adjustments for "Many to Many on self": do not get the resulting models here directly, but rather
        // just set the columns to select and do some adjustments to also select the "inverse" records
        $builder->addSelect(
            $this->shouldSelect($columns)
        );

        // backup order directives
        $orders = $builder->getQuery()->orders;
        $builder->getQuery()->orders = [];

        // clone the original query
        $query2 = clone($this->query);

        // determine the columns to select - same as in original query, but with inverted pivot key names
        $query2->select(
            $this->shouldSelectInverse( $columns )
        );
        // remove the inner join and build a new one, this time using the "foreign" pivot key
        $query2->getQuery()->joins = array();

        $baseTable = $this->related->getTable();
        $key = $baseTable.'.'.$this->relatedKey;
        $query2->join($this->table, $key, '=', $this->getQualifiedForeignPivotKeyName());

        // go through all where conditions and "invert" the one relevant for the inner join
        foreach( $query2->getQuery()->wheres as &$where ) {
            if(
                $where['type'] == 'Basic'
                && $where['column'] == $this->getQualifiedForeignPivotKeyName()
                && $where['operator'] == '='
                && $where['value'] == $this->parent->{$this->parentKey}
            ) {
                $where['column'] = $this->getQualifiedRelatedPivotKeyName();
                break;
            }
        }

        // add the duplicated and modified and adjusted query to the original query with union
        $builder->getQuery()->union($query2);

        // reapply orderings so that they are used for the "union" rather than just the individual queries
        foreach($orders as $ord)
            $builder->getQuery()->orderBy($ord['column'], $ord['direction']);

        // back to "normal" - get the models
        $models = $builder->getModels();
        $this->hydratePivotRelation($models);

        // If we actually found models we will also eager load any relationships that
        // have been specified as needing to be eager loaded. This will solve the
        // n + 1 query problem for the developer and also increase performance.
        if (count($models) > 0) {
            $models = $builder->eagerLoadRelations($models);
        }

        return $this->related->newCollection($models);
    }


    /**
     * Get the select columns for the relation query.
     *
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return array
     */
    protected function shouldSelectInverse(array $columns = ['*'])
    {
        if ($columns == ['*']) {
            $columns = [$this->related->getTable().'.*'];
        }

        return array_merge($columns, $this->aliasedPivotColumnsInverse());
    }

    /**
     * Get the pivot columns for the relation.
     *
     * "pivot_" is prefixed ot each column for easy removal later.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function aliasedPivotColumnsInverse()
    {
        $collection = collect( $this->pivotColumns )->map(function ($column) {
            return $this->table.'.'.$column.' as pivot_'.$column;
        });
        $collection->prepend(
            $this->table.'.'.$this->relatedPivotKey.' as pivot_'.$this->foreignPivotKey
        );
        $collection->prepend(
            $this->table.'.'.$this->foreignPivotKey.' as pivot_'.$this->relatedPivotKey
        );

        return $collection->unique()->all();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem quite some time ago and have thus been following this problem closely and have made a lot of research. I have come across some of the solutions you have also found, and some more, and also have thought of other solutions that I summed [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/441#issuecomment-14213883), mostly how to get both user_ids in the same column. I am afraid they will all not work well. I am also afraid that using any custom classes will stop you from using all of Laravel's handy relation features (especially eager loading). So I still thought what one could do, and, until one comes up with a hasMany-function on many columns, I think I have come up with a possible solution yesterday. I will show it first and then apply it to your project.

## My project

### Initial solution

In my project, one user partners with another one (= partnership) and then later will be assigned a commission. So I had the following tables:

```
USERS
id       | name
---------|------
1        | foo
2        | bar
17       | baz
20       | Joe
48       | Jane
51       | Jim 

PARTNERSHIPS
id  | partner1  | partner2  | confirmed | other_columns
----|-----------|-----------|-----------|---------------
1   | 1         | 2         | 1         |
9   | 17        | 20        | 1         |
23  | 48        | 51        | 1         |
```

As each user should always have only one active partnership, the non-active being soft-deleted, I could have helped myself by just using the `hasMany` function twice:

```
//user.php
public function partnerships()
{
    $r = $this->hasMany(Partnership::class, 'partner1');

    if(! $r->count() ){
        $r = $this->hasMany(Partnership::class, 'partner2');
    }

    return $r;
}
```

But if I had wanted to lookup all partnerships of a user, current and past, this of course, wouldn't have worked.

### New solution

Yesterday, I came up with the solution, that is close to yours, of using a pivot table but with a little difference of using another table:

```
USERS
(same as above)

PARTNERSHIP_USER
user_id | partnership_id 
--------|----------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
17      | 9
20      | 9
48      | 23
51      | 23

PARTNERSHIPS
id  | confirmed | other_columns
----|-----------|---------------
1   | 1         |
9   | 1         |
23  | 1         |

// user.php
public function partnerships(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Partnership::class);
}

public function getPartners(){
    return $this->partnerships()->with(['users' => function ($query){
        $query->where('user_id', '<>', $this->id);
    }])->get();
}

public function getCurrentPartner(){
    return $this->partnerships()->latest()->with(['users' => function ($query){
       $query->where('user_id', '<>', $this->id);
    }])->get();
}


// partnership.php
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Of course, this comes with the drawback that you always have to create and maintain two entrances in the pivot table but I think this occasional extra load for the database -- how often will this be altered anyway? -- is preferable to having two select queries on two columns every time (and from your example it seemed that you duplicated the entries in your friends table anyway).

## Applied to your project

In your example the tables could be structured like this:

```
USERS
id       | name
---------|------
1        | foo
2        | bar
3        | baz

FRIENDSHIP_USER
user_id  | friendship_id
---------|------
1        | 1
2        | 1
3        | 2
1        | 2

FRIENDSHIPS 
id      |send_id* | receive_id* | is_blocked | [all the other nice stuff
--------|---------|-------------|------------|- you want to save]
1       | 1       |    2        |  0         |
2       | 3       |    1        |  0         |

[*send_id and receive_id are optional except 
you really want to save who did what]
```

Edit: My `$user->partners()` looks like this:

```
// user.php

// PARTNERSHIPS
public function partnerships(){
    // 'failed' is a custom fields in the pivot table, like the 'is_blocked' in your example
    return $this->belongsToMany(Partnership::class)
        ->withPivot('failed');
}

// PARTNERS
public function partners(){
    // this query goes forth to partnerships and then back to users.
    // The subquery excludes the id of the querying user when going back
    // (when I ask for "partners", I want only the second person to be returned)
    return $this->partnerships()
        ->with(['users' => function ($query){
                $query->where('user_id', '<>', $this->id);
        }]);
}
```