# Last User Contacted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model and a `Message` one with `sender_id` and `recipient_id`.

I would like to retrieve all **users** I have contacted or have been contacted by.

I tried :

```
  has_many :message_received_by_user, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :recipient_id, select: "DISTINCT ON (messages.sender_id) messages.sender_id, messages.created_at, messages.body" , order: "messages.sender_id, messages.created_at DESC"
```

But this only give me one side (those who contacted me).

How can I have both sides ?

Many thanks

Comment: has many relationship has to be plural (message_received_by_users) and belongs to singular.

Comment: Does that means I can't achieve what I would like to do using `has_many` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below this section is my original answer; I mis-read the question and thought the OP only wanted a list of users who had RECEIVED messages from the specified user; I didn't notice the part about also users who SENT messages to the specified user as well. Here is my update. I'll leave the original answer below in case it helps.

In this version of the answer, I would alter the join and the where clause so that the query examines either the `sender_id` or `recipient_id` column:

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN messages ON (messages.sender_id = users.id OR messages.recipient_id = users.id)")
    .where("messages.sender_id = ? OR messages.recipient_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id).uniq
```

Apologies for the misunderstanding.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

In order to get all the users you've contacted, I am thinking the easiest approach is to do this through the normal active record query methods. First, set up the `has_many` in your `User` model like so:

In your `User` model

```
has_many :messages_sent, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: :sender_id
has_many :messages_received, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: :recipient_id
```

And then, you can simply query using the relationship like so:

```
User.joins(:messages_received).where(:messages=>{sender_id: current_user.id}).uniq
```

Note: replace `current_user` with whatever you use to store the target user.

**Edit**

Someone asked why this is better than using the direct `:messages_sent` relationship. The advantage this approach has is that it is all done on the database level, where proper indexing can do its job. If you have a very large table, and this user has sent a large number of messages, using the active record `has_many` relationship will require you to iterate over a large collection, attempting to find unique users.

Just to add a bit more clarification, this query should render an SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users INNER JOIN messages ON messages.recipient_id = users.id 
WHERE messages.sender_id = 1
```

In plain English, this is basically saying to the database: "Please give me all the users who RECEIVED a message SENT by user #1".

Comment: Yeah that was me! I deleted the comment because I didn't read the question correctly! Your answer is still missing a way to get users that either sent or received messages to the target user, but i'm not sure that's possible in one query without writing SQL

Comment: @Slicedpan No problem, it was a fair question. Hmm I'm not quite sure what you mean (re: second part of your comment). The active record query methods are being invoked on the `User` model. Ultimately, this will generate a query that looks like this: `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN messages ON messages.recipient_id = users.id WHERE messages.sender_id = 1`. As you can see (unless I'm really missing something), you do indeed get back a list of users who received messages from the target user.

Comment: I think the query you need is `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN messages  AS r_msg ON r_msg.recipient_id = users.id INNER JOIN messages AS s_msg ON s_msg.sender_id = users.id WHERE s_msg.recipient_id = 1 OR r_msg.recipient_id = 1;` i.e. all users who received a message from user 1 or sent a message to user 1

Comment: @Slicedpan Oh nuts, I see what you're saying. I mis-read the question and thought the OP only wanted users who RECEIVED messages, not users who SENT messages to this user. Thank you! I'll update.

Comment: I think doing `User.joins(:messages_sent, :messages_received)` will automatically create aliases, but I can't find a definitive source as to what the alias will be.

Comment: @Slicedpan I've never noticed it creating aliases, but not sure. Answer updated; The INNER JOIN also needs to `OR` as well I believe, otherwise having the second INNER JOIN will cut out anything that was matched by the first INNER JOIN, since INNER JOIN intersects rows.

Comment: to get last message from these users : `Message.select("DISTINCT ON (messages.sender_id) messages.*")
    .joins("INNER JOIN users ON (messages.sender_id = users.id OR messages.recipient_id = users.id)")
    .where("messages.sender_id = ? OR messages.recipient_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
    .order("messages.sender_id,messages.created_at DESC")`

Comment: Think you have it now, I would suggest abstracting that into a scope: `scope :corresponded_with, ->(u) { #the query }`, so you can do `User.corresponded_with(current_user)` or whatever

Comment: @titibouboul I agree with Slicedpan, you can put this in a scope and clean things up very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

your migration will look like this:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :messages do |t|
    def up
      t.references :sender
      t.references :recipient
      t.string :message
    end
  end
end
```

You model:-

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name => 'User'
end
```

And these other are the associations on the other side (the user model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
 has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end
```

This will allow you to get all of a user's sent or received messages like this:

```
@user.sent_messages
@user.received_messages
```

Thanks

Comment: I would like distinct users, not messages !

Answer (score 0):

refer railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association or [How to Implement a Friendship Model in Rails 3 for a Social Networking Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612736/how-to-implement-a-friendship-model-in-rails-3-for-a-social-networking-applicati)

I implement it in mongoid as

User model

```
has_many :friendships, inverse_of: :owner

def friends
  #retrive all the friendships and collect users have sent me a request or being sent a  request.
  fs = Friendship.any_of({:friend_id.in => [self.id]}, {:owner_id.in => [self.id]}).where(state: 'accepted')
  User.in(id: fs.collect{|i| [i.friend_id, i.owner_id]}.flatten - [self.id])
end
```

Friendship model

```
 belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User' #user who sent friend request is the owner
 belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User" #user to whom request is sent.
```